# How to remove an EventListener that someone else created?

Tags: javascript, event-listener, famo.us

A library (famo.us) i'm using inserts an event listener into the window that breaks scrollviews. For various pipeline reasons its difficult to modify the library so is there a way to remove an event listener that some other code added?

My understanding is that i need access to the actual function definition when calling the remove call also.

I tried as below, to get the handler reference and then remove it, but without luck.

```
> getEventListeners(window).touchmove
[
Object
listener: function (event) {
remove: function ()
type: "touchmove"
useCapture: true
__proto__: Object
]

> f=getEventListeners(window).touchmove
[
Object
]

> window.removeEventListener('touchmove', f)
undefined

> getEventListeners(window)
Object {message: Array[1], load: Array[2], unload: Array[1], online: Array[1], resize: Array[1]…}
load: Array[2]
message: Array[1]
online: Array[1]
popstate: Array[1]
resize: Array[1]
touchmove: Array[1]     <<< bugger is still there!
unload: Array[1]
```

Comment: You can always override it with `window.ontouchmove = return false;` but that probably has some side effects as well. Otherwise it will be hard to remove the event listener without the actual named function that was bound.

Comment: There's no way to do that if you haven't the reference to the attached listener. One dirty trick would be trying to *replace* the element, but you'd lose *all* the event listeners and anyway you can't do that on `window`. @adeneo Using the traditional event registering doesn't remove listeners added using `addEventListener`.

Comment: @MaxArt - It does not remove the event listener, but handlers added as properties will execute first, so you could return false, and as such override it.

Comment: @adeneo It doesn't, you can try it yourself. The only way to achieve that is to call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, but that would prevent calling the listeners added after that, and anyway it's not available on older IE.

Comment: @MaxArt - I did try it -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TaR9e/

Comment: the main issue here is that the library is swallowing touch events, and i want to revert to normal behavior. adding a separate method that intercepts them may work, but is there a way to pass/propagate touch Events directly to the native handlers?
related to https://github.com/Famous/core/issues/14

Comment: @adeneo What kind of syntax is `window.onclick = return false;`? I used to think that you used it for brevity, but you should actually do `window.onclick = function() {return false;};`. It "works" because it throws a syntax error.

Comment: @dcsan The only thing I can suggest at this point, if you don't want to change the code of the library, is to override `window.addEventListener` (or `window.attachEvent` if you want to have IE8- compatibility), and try to intercept the calls, but that's quite a lot of hassle.

Comment: I also tried overriding the event below before the library is loaded.
`window.addEventListener = function(fn) {
        console.log('tried to addEventListener', fn);
    }`
but still struggling with load order (its a meteor app so there are layers of magic to unravel...)

Comment: `getEventListeners` is just a dev tool API (as far as I know) so I'm not sure it would work in code. That said, in you can see that "f" has a property that is a function called "remove" - try calling that. `f.remove()`. Or since `useCapture` is true, try `window.removeEventListener('touchmove', f.listener, true)`